# Listen for Query FAILED_PRECONDITION The query requires an index

Tags: firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to perform a compound query with multiple indexes. But I get the following error

> Listen for Query( collectionGroup=groupNotifications where receivers array_contains jPvdUmIb05aeZeRPtFTwX3idKPm1 order by -createdAt) failed: Status{code=FAILED_PRECONDITION, description=The query requires an index.

This is my query

```
  Future<GroupNotificationModel> latestGroupNotification() async => _firestore
      .collectionGroup('groupNotifications')
      .where('receivers', arrayContains: user.id)
      .orderBy('createdAt', descending: true)
      .limit(1)
      .getDocuments()
      .then((value) => GroupNotificationModel.fromMap(value.documents.first.data));
```

and I set my indexes in the following way

[image]

So why do I get the error? I added the indexes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was to put the indexes in the right order

[image]